# Points on $k$ Circles

Tags: discrete-geometry, incidence-geometry

Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. We want to find the minimum number $f(k)$, such that for a set of finite points in the plane, if any $f(k)$ of them are on $k$ circles, then all of them are on $k$ circles.

For example $f(1)=4$ (trivial) and $f(2)=9$.

Can you find some bounds for $f(k)$?

p.s. We know the answer for "line" instead of "circle" is $f(k)=\binom{k+2}{2}$.

Comment: I think providing some more related results and links would be useful.

Comment: The number  $f(k)-1$ is also the minimum  $n$  such that for any set of $n$ points $S$ in the plane there is at most a union of $k$ circles $X=C_1\cup\dots\cup C_k$ such that $S\subset X$, isn't it?

Comment: Although I don't doubt it, I would appreciate a proof sketch that $f(2)=9$.

Comment: An interesting variant might be to replace "$k$ circles" by "$k$ unit-radius circles."

Comment: @PietroMajer No, the number $f(k)−1$ is the maximum n such that there exist a set $S$ of points $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ such that for each $i$, $S−P_i$ is on $k$ circles but the whole $S$ is not.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke The sketch of proof for f(2)=9 is using some cases for those nine points, 5+4 or 6+3 or..., then replacing one of them with the new point (10th point). The counterexample for 8 is three circles with their pairwise intersections (6 points) and one extra point on each of them. I think the answer for "unit circles" is very small.

Comment: (@Morteza: the quantity I defined above is larger than or equal to $f(k)-1$; I was asking if it coincides...)

Comment: @PietroMajer No I think, for example for $k=2$, we have $f(k)=9$, but your parameter is $6$. Your parameter is exactly $3k$, isn't it?